dataverse plugin registration tool fail to capture debug profile
i got the plugin to execute and can trace print fine.
But when I try to debug it power app won't let me submit my form. I select a Step with "Create" message to Start Profiling, then on my web browser I try to create a new record. This is when the app fail to submit. The message I am getting is the following (see below). It looks like something is wrong with my plugin registration tool (I am new to plugins development and I've only downloaded my PRT recently. I think i have the latest version).
Error message when creating new record:

"@Microsoft.PowerApps.CDS.ErrorDetails.Plugin.PluginTrace": "An exception occurred during the initialization of the Plug-in Profiler.\r\n
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.\r\n
Parameter name: s\r\n
   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)\r\n
   at PluginProfiler.Plugins.PluginLoaderUtility.RefreshAssembly(IOrganizationService service, ProfilerConfiguration config, PluginInitializationContext context)\r\n
   at PluginProfiler.Plugins.PluginLoaderUtility.RefreshPluginInitializationContext(IOrganizationServiceFactory factory, ProfilerConfiguration config, PluginInitializationContext currentContext)\r\n
   at PluginProfiler.Plugins.ProfilerBase`1.InitializeProfiler(Dictionary`2 services, T operationContext, ProfilerPluginContext& context)\r\n",
"@Microsoft.PowerApps.CDS.HelpLink": "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398563&error=Microsoft.Crm.CrmException%3a80040265&client=platform",
"@Microsoft.PowerApps.CDS.TraceText": "\r\n
[PluginProfiler.Plugins: PluginProfiler.Plugins.ProfilerPlugin]\r\n
[55308ac5-4137-ef11-8409-002248293634: HelloPlugin.SetupNewWorkflowInstance: Create of nci_tblmailrequest (Profiler)]\r\n\r\n\t\r\n\t
An exception occurred during the initialization of the Plug-in Profiler.\r\n\t
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.\r\n\t
Parameter name: s\r\n\t   
   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)\r\n\t   
   at PluginProfiler.Plugins.PluginLoaderUtility.RefreshAssembly(IOrganizationService service, ProfilerConfiguration config, PluginInitializationContext context)\r\n\t   
   at PluginProfiler.Plugins.PluginLoaderUtility.RefreshPluginInitializationContext(IOrganizationServiceFactory factory, ProfilerConfiguration config, PluginInitializationContext currentContext)\r\n\t   
at PluginProfiler.Plugins.ProfilerBase`1.InitializeProfiler(Dictionary`2 services, T operationContext, ProfilerPluginContext& context)\r\n\t\r\n\t\r\n",
"@Microsoft.PowerApps.CDS.InnerError.Message": "Unexpected Exception in the Plug-in Profiler"

